# Running PORT exposure on Microsoft Server

Tags: windows, azure, windows-firewall, azure-networking, windows-server-2022

So this is admittedly a very n00b question on Microsoft Server, so please assume basic knowledge and be kind :). I do, however, feel I have a good knowledge of Linux networking concepts, but I am failing miserably with Microsoft.

So, I am attempting to open up a port connection to my running Microsoft Server on port 11111 to connect to a running web application on that port. From within the Remote Desktop Program I am able to connect to the port on 127.0.0.1 and localhost.

[image]

So, I have confirmed that the app server is working and can send responses on port 11111.

However, I couldn't connect to this from outside the RDP instance, let's say I have been allocated the IP address 100.01.02.03 for argument sake. I navigate to 100.01.02.03:11111 in the browser, and the connection hangs.

So, what I have diagnosed is that the port is closed to outside connections. I followed some nice guides on how to open a port in Windows Server Firewall, and opened the port following the relevant documentation:

[image]

I am confident that this is correct.

As my Microsoft Server is via an Azure Cloud instance, I have also added the inbound port rule to the Network security group associated to the VM running the server as follows:

[image]

However, I still can not connect to 100.01.02.03:11111 from another device ... :(

Being a n00b/hobbyist, I am not sure what else I would need to do ... I'd be very grateful for help in debugging or diagnosing what I may have done wrong, or some extra pointers or documentation or guides to be able to get this connection working.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the port is open in the Network Secrurity Group that has been assigned to the VM has the port open. Take a look at [this article](https://samcogan.com/cloud-support-cant-access-service-on-my-virtual-machine/) on how to do that.